# How to auto truncate transaction log of SharePoint Database?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, database-server

We need to auto truncate the transaction log of SharePoint Database in our server as it gets full and as a result it does not accommodate any data further received from the lists. Hence, need how to auto truncate the same to stop any further data hurdles.

Answer (score 1):

Run a Transaction Log backup on a regular basis. This will maintain the LDF size. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191429.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179478.aspx for reference. You can either do this within a Maintenance Plan, or use T-SQL using `BACKUP LOG`.

Comment: Is there a provision of doing it automatically? OR setting a timer or so?

Comment: We need backup and also truncate
to do it automatically.

Comment: Not within SharePoint, no. You'll need to use T-SQL (can schedule with a SQL Agent job), Maintenance Plan (which can be scheduled as well), or PowerShell (which you could schedule via Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Do you have any referral links to do so?

Comment: Take a look at the second link I provided in my answer. That gives you all 4 methods (with the Maintenance Plan information linked out to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191002.aspx).